Momentum distribution of nucleons inside the deuteron (Paris potential)
I am looking for a graph that shows the momentum distribution of nucleons inside the deuteron.
Side note: I know that several models for nucleon-nucleon potentials exist, such as the Paris, Bonn or Moscow potential. Most of the papers show coupling strengths with respect to nucleon distance, but I am specifically interested in the momentum distribution. More specifically: I need a plot that shows the momentum of a single nucleon inside the deuteron in MeV on the x axis and the probability of that momentum to occur on the y axis. Preferably as a result of the Paris model, but other models work as well.
Could anyone provide a source? Thanks in advance!
EDIT: JEB provided me with the Argonne momentum distribution, but it would still be useful for me to have the Paris momentum distribution for comparison. The original Paris paper does not show any momentum distribution (see original paper here).

You forgot the Argonne V-18 potential:
https://www.phy.anl.gov/theory/research/momenta/


I am a little confused by the units. Assuming we use the relation $\hbar c = 197 MeV fm$ and natural units, then $1/fm = 197 MeV/(\hbar c) = 197 MeV$. That would mean at a highly probable $p$, let's just take $p=1*(1/fm)$, we have a momentum of $p=197MeV$, which seems to be really big if we consider that the binding energy of the deuteron is just $2.2 MeV$. What am I getting wrong?

What you're getting wrong is saying you're confused. You're just surprised. Yes, the deuteron is weakly bound, but the charge radius is 2.1778(12) fm, and the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle says to  confine something to the volume, you need momentum uncertainty on the order of a few hundred MeV/c.
